# Unable to create new instance of marrionette app

Tags: runtime-error, marionette, listen, backbone-rails

Hi I have installed the latest version of 'marionette-rails' and 'rails-backbone' for my web app but am having issues in creating a new marrionette instance.

This is what I did in my web console

```
App = new Marionette.Application()
```

After which I see this error

```
TypeError: this.listenTo is not a function
```

[image]

Has this got to do with the versioning of marionette or backbone?

How do I get around this so that I can create an instance of marionette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that the issue was due to a old version of rails-backbone. I did a gem update to get the latest version of rails-backbone which did the job